# SSRS 2008 R2 Subreport Will Not Display

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-2008-r2

I've looked through all the other topics on this subject but I cannot find an answer. I have a report that utilizes a dataset that runs a stored procedure. That SP returns two rows, both of which I can display in a table in the report. So far so good.

Next, I added a tablix which uses the same dataset. In the (only cell in the) detail row of the tablix I added a subreport. I added the parameters to the subreport (four of which come from the dataset and one of which comes from a main report parameter). I created a row group tied to an Id column on the dataset.

What I expect to see when I run the main report: two instances of the subreport, one for each of the two rows returned by the SP.

What I actually see: In ReportBuilder I only get the first instance of the subreport. If I call the report service from an application (rendering it as a .PDF) nothing of the subreport shows at all. In either environment, there are no errors showing in the report.

What I've checked: I made sure all the various visibility options in the tablix, the row group, the subreport, etc. were set to always show. I also added some text to the subreport's NoRowsMessageproperty. That text is shown (one for each row) for the subreport when I try to run it from the Report Service. Why this would happen I also don't know, as the parameter values I supply are identical in both cases.

My guess is that I've got something wrong in the way I'm doing the row group, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Hi, I am doing something similar to you, however I am using List. Can you try changing from tables to lists to see if that works for you?

Comment: Are you placing the Tablix in the grouped header/footer by mistake or is it in the detail row of the two row dataset?

Comment: @Shruti good idea. Unfortunately I get nothing back whatsoever when using a list. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Irb Yeah, the subreport is in the detail row. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just created a new (blank) report and recreated the tablix. Even though I used the same data source/row group/parameters, etc. it worked just fine. I have no idea why. I copied the working tablix in to the broken report and it still didn't render correctly. Again, I have no idea why. However, I got it working by just starting over. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the subreport in a rectangle, I did a report that way in which the subreport pagebreaked after each instance.

I would make sure the rectangle with the subreport in it is under the group row in your tablix.

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, no luck with that. Thanks for the suggestion though as that did help me out with a completely different report.